# How to measure the fixed effect of a pair of individuals using the plm package in R?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I have a panel data set consisting of bonds with daily prices observed over a period of time. Thus each bond is repeated downwards with the corresponding daily price observations and dates (ref picture below). Half of the bonds are green (identified by a dummy variable) and each green bond is matched with a non-green bond, each pair is identified with a pair-id. So a green bond and its matched non-green bond have the same pair-id, and are observed over the same time span (say 100 days each), but the individual bond-id is unique.

[image: Paneldata, screenshot]

I want to measure the fixed effect within each pair of bonds to figure out if there is a significant difference in yield to maturity (variable used = ask.yield) between the green bond and its matching non-green bond. Thus, I believe when identifying the paneldata in R, that the individual should be pair.id and the time index should be date. I use the following regression:

```
fixed <- plm(ask.yield ~ liquidity + green, data = paneldata, index = c(“pair.id”, “dates”), model = “within”)
```

Desired output (do not mind the numbers):

[image: img2]

I get an error message saying:

> Error in pdim.default(index[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6gDK.png)], index[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpd3X.png)]) : 
>   duplicate couples (id-time)

I understand the error message – each pair.id in the panel data is recorded over the same dates twice (one time for the green bond, and one for the matching non-green bond).

Does anyone know how to get around this problem and still be able to measure the fixed effect within each pair of bonds?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, there are duplications in the paired id, aka, the combination of `pair.id` and `dates` are not unique. Can you check whether the values of `date` unique for each `pair.id`?

If they are, you might need to convert the `date` to `str`, depending on the data type, the date might be converted to some value that might introduce the duplication values.

Hope this helps, since I don't have the data, I have no way to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Bill Chen ! It is correct that the dates are not unique for each pair.id. That is because for each pair.id, we are observing two bonds (one green and one non-green) over the same period of time.  So each date will be observed two times within each pair.id. And i understand that this is the problem (in regards to the error), but I would really like a way to get around it so that I can extract the fixed effect within each pair of bonds. I will try to convert the date to str as you say. If there is a way to add a dataset here, I would be happy to do it

Comment: @kakaka leave a link with dropbox or something.